# Citing specific slides of a presentation

Tags: biblatex

I encouter the following problem to which I simply can't find a solution.

I'm working on a homework, and I want to cite the slides the professor gave us.
So, if I type `\cite[20]{presentationOne}` I want `[1, F. 20]` as result and not `[1, S. 20]`.
(F. for Folie, and S. for Seite, I'm from Germany).

I'm citing books as well, therefore simply changing it for all citations isn't a solution.

I use `biblatex` with biber backend.

Hope anyone got a clean solution for this. Otherwise I would have to mention in the foreword what I mean with those citations.

Comment: You could use `\cite[F.~20]{presentationOne}` when citing the presentation. Do you want an automatic solution for certain entries?

Comment: For my work now, your comment solves my problem. But I think for future readers, with longer documents and more citations than mine, an automatic solution would be nice. So if you know one it would be nice.

Comment: Do you have a special bibliography driver for presentations?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel No, I don't have any. Would you recommend one?

Comment: If you have a special driver like `presentation` you can setup the formation of the optional key by `\DeclareFieldFormat[presentation]{postnote}{F~#1}` or some other modification related to the driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this:

1. You can just use something like `\cite[F.~20]{reference}`. Whenever the optional argument is more than just a number, then `biblatex` outputs it literally instead of putting a pagination string in front of it.¹
2. As already mentioned in a comment to your question, you could define a separate bibliography driver `presentation` for presentations. Then you could just define a specific postnote style with `\DeclareFieldFormat[presentation]{postnote}{F~#1}` or something similar. This would some kind of a global solution.
3. For every item in your `.bib` file you can set the `pagination = {page|column|line|verse|section|paragraph|none}` field. `biblatex` evaluates this field and changes its formatting of the postnotes according to the value of the `pagination` field.

   3.1 You could now just set the pagination field to `none` which will already prevent `biblatex` from printing a "p." before the number, but you will still have to care about setting the "F.~" at the right places.

   3.2 You could abuse one of the default types (`column`, `verse` etc.) to use it in your case. In this case you must give your `.bib` entry for example a `pagination = {verse}` field and redefine the corresponding `verse` locale to fit your needs by `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{verse = {Folie}, verses = {Folien}}`.

   3.3 I didn't have a look into the code of `biblatex` but I think it may be possible to copy and modify the code for the pagination command to add another value (something like `slide`) to the `paginantion` type list. On the long run, this would be the cleanest but also most invasive method to solve your problem.

––

¹ This is not exactly the whole story, as there are also the commands like `\psq` to announce "and following pages". But everything that differs from a number and those special commands is just printed by biblatex without further processing.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [Benedikt Bauer's wonderful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101475/35864), it is actually not very hard to define one's own pagination style (point 3.3).

`biblatex` treats the `pagination` field in a way very convenient for us:

The `pagination` field takes a key, such as the standard keys `page`, `column`, `line`, `verse`, `section`, `paragraph` or `none`. `biblatex` reads the key and tries to put the `bibstring` named after the key before the page numbers; except, of course, for the case in which `pagination` is `none`, in that case no bibstring is inserted.

So if we define two new `bibliography` strings `slide` and `slides`, we can then specify `pagination = {slide}` in the `.bib` entry and are good to go.

```
\NewBibliographyString{slide,slides}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  slide   = {F\adddot},%{Folie}
  slides  = {F\adddot},%{Folien}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  slide   = {s\adddot},%{slide}
  slides  = {ss\adddot},%{slides}
}
```

Unfortunately, `\DefineBibliographyStrings`, which can be used in the preamble, does not support short and long `bibstrings`; if you want those, you will have to define your own `.lbx` file inheriting all the other features, but adding `slide` and `slides`.

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-slides.lbx}[2013/10/15 ngerman with slides]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\NewBibliographyString{slide,slides}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit   = {ngerman},
  slide     = {{Folie}{F\adddot}},
  slides    = {{Folien}{F\adddot}},
}
```

This language definition can then be loaded via `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-slides}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{DahmenReusken:Interpolation,
  author          = {Wolfgang Dahmen and Arnold Reusken},
  title           = {Interpolation},
  chapter         = {8},
  booktitle       = {Numerik für Ingenieure und Naturwissenschaftler},
  booktitleaddon  = {Folien für Dozenten},
  date            = {2007-11-21},
  url             = {https://www.igpm.rwth-aachen.de/Download/DahmenReusken/Folien/Kapitel8.pdf},
  urldate         = {2013-08-11},
  pagination      = {slide},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{slide,slides}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  slide   = {F\adddot},%{Folie}
  slides  = {F\adddot},%{Folien}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  slide   = {s\adddot},%{slide}
  slides  = {ss\adddot},%{slides}
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \parencite[vgl.][4]{DahmenReusken:Interpolation}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]