# Online journal pages field that is compatible with natbib+bibtex and biblatex+biber?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I want to know how I should properly use the provided page field of an article published in an online journal (such as PLoS Computational Biology).

Even though articles published in online journals do not have actual page numbers, both the journals themselves and Google Scholar provide a `pages` field holding values such as `e1000112` (PLoS) and `20122863` (Proceedings of the Royal Society).

Semantics aside, using the `pages` field for this would be a non-issue, but the fact that the second value does not start with a letter means that the printed citation shows `p. 20122863` which is wrong because that number is not an actual page number.

Also, it seems to me that the `pages` field should not be used for this purpose, so I tried to find an alternative and found `eid` [[source]](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/BibtexHelp.php):

> ## eid
>
> The Electronic identifier is for electronic journals that also appear in print. This number replaces the page number, and is used to find the article within the printed volume. Sometimes also called citation number.

But I am not sure whether this is suitable because it mentions printed volumes and I am positive that not every online journal ends up publishing printed volumes.

## Question:

> What field should I use for the pages field provided by online journals that is compatible with both `natbib`+`bibtex` and `biblatex`+`biber`?

Comment: With `biblatex` it would probably be no problem to use the `pages` field and use `pagination={none}` in those cases. To say how a solution might work with `natbib`, we would need to know what style you use, as the `.bst` file decides what gets printed, and how it is going to look.

Comment: @moewe I am not interested in a specific style -- my main concern is the proper formatting of my `.bib` files such that `biblatex` and `natbib` can access and show the field correctly. Also, I want to avoid a `biblatex`-only solution as switch between `biblatex` and `natbib` for different projects. Is `eid` not the right field to use? What happens when `pages={e1000112}` that prevents pagination from appearing (I assume it's the `e`)? It seems that best option would be to use something in the `pages` field that prevents pagination.

Comment: It is the style (bst for natbib) which decides if and how to print the content of field. If the style doesn't support a special pagination style it is perhaps possible to find some trick to get around it but imho there never will be a general solution working for all natbib compatible styles. E.g. styles which don't know the eid field will simply ignore it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I am aware that if the style does not support, for example, `eid`, then there's no point in using it. Hence, I am now in search of a work-around. I tried to adapt Mico's answer from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31411/32206) by using `pages={\noop{e}20122863}`), but it does not disable pagination. `e` is not typeset as expected, but `p.` is typeset.

Comment: The page field looks like the more likely candidate for a universal solution as I imagine that not all styles are able to deal with the `eid`. But as Ulrike Fischer says (and I mentioned above), it is the `.bst` who decides the output, and if the `.bst` file always prints "p." in front of the pages field and allows for no mechanism to disable this behaviour, you will have to live with that. A universal solution that works with *everything* seems quite unlikely.

Comment: The `\noop` command will not disable any page prefixing, it will make BibTeX see the "e", but will suppress it in the final output (which is probably not what you want at all). `biblatex` checks if the `pages` field contains something that looks like a page range (numbers and some special characters), if not the page prefix is disabled. As you correctly guess the "e" tells `biblatex` this is not a proper range field.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I understand that a universal solution is all but impossible. I'd be more than happy with a solution that does not typeset `p.`/`pp.` when the `pages` field starts with a letter, as in the example above starting with `e`. This is the current behaviour actually. However, I would also like to "fool" the page(-range) check by using something like `\noop{e}123456`. This will mean that `e` is not typeset but `p.`/`pp.` are not typeset either.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether all styles do actually check the pages field for "number-range-ness" (`biblatex` does, but I imagine not all `natbib` `.bst` files do). As such a work-around like this might work with some styles (not a lot actually, I suppose), but is useless as the universal solution you want it to be.

Comment: As you now have been told more than once: It depends on the style how the page number is printed. And as you didn't say which style(s) you want to use it is impossible to say if there exist a solution for them.

Comment: With `biblatex`, however, you do not have to trick `biblatex` into thinking the `pages` field does not contain a proper page range when it does, a simple `pagination = {none}` in the `.bib` entry to that particular item suffices to tell `biblatex` that you do not wish to see any "p."/"pp." stuff.

Comment: How do you come to the assessment that "a universal solution is all but impossible", if you look around on this site, you will find that a lot of fixes and modifications are heavily style-specific and -dependant. As the `eid` field is probably newer than some styles (there are styles out there without URL support! as they pre-date the advent of the modern internet) and the pages number range check is not a standard function in BibTeX AFAIK, there is bound to be some style (quite a lot actually) that these solutions do not work with.

Comment: The best you can hope for is a solution that is widely applicable (and at least applicable to all the styles you use at the moment, and maybe are likely to use in the future) and easy to implement if one has to modify other styles. But even that seems like a herculean and/or Sisyphean task.

Comment: @moewe @UlrikeFischer: Thanks a lot for your comments! I now understand why a universal solution is impossible. I'll gladly accept a short explanation on why that is so along with the `pagination={none}` `biblatex` option as an answer. You have both been extremely helpful!

Comment: @moewe At least in British English, 'a universal solution is all but impossible' *means* 'a universal solution is nearly/almost impossible'. I think you are seeing recalcitrance where only agreement is to be found ;).

Comment: @cfr Ahhh well, the English language (and not only the British version apparently, "all but" seems to be an idiom in all varieties of the English language) has thrown me once again; I might have been a bit more insistent than necessary.

Comment: @moewe It was not until I read your comments that I realised just how illogical it is... :).

Comment: @moewe Seems like I've created a mess! `:-)` Apologies. But yes, I did mean that a universal solution is impossible. The `biblatex`-only solution will have to do for now. By the way, the correct option to use is `bookpagination = {none}`; `pagination` is used for in-text citations as far as I can tell. So thanks. Feel free to write up a short answer so that I can give credit where it's due!

Comment: No need to apologise (after all it was not you who messed up the understanding of the English language). I really hope I did not come across too impatient and harsh/rude. I came up with an answer, it is not short though. Hope you're still fine with it.

Comment: @moewe You didn't come across as impatient, harsh or rude. Au contraire - I always find how patient people on this website are when dealing with `n00b`s like me surprising. `:-)` So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: A universal solution is very nearly impossible, `biblatex` offers the `bookpagination` (and `pagination` field) and a well-coded style will make use of those, so `bookpagination = {none}` seems a good way to go for `biblatex`.

**The Long Answer**

A solution that works for both `natbib` and `biblatex` is almost impossible (one might say all but impossible) for the simple reason that it is not `natbib` or `biblatex` that decides what is printed and how the bibliography looks like, but the bibliography style (`\bibliographystyle` in "BibTeX packages"<sub>for lack of a better name</sub> [the `.bst` styles]; `style`, `bibstyle` with `biblatex` [the `.bbx` styles]); so a universal solution would have to work with *all* the styles (`.bst` as well as `.bbx`) available today - that is quite a lot of styles.

While most of the styles adhere to a general semantics and best practice, we cannot be sure that all styles will display, say, the `pages` field in a certain way (well, we can be quite sure with the `pages` field as it is so essential and standard, but the `eid` field is a different matter altogether).

Most of the "exotic" fields such as `eid`, `eprint` etc. are bound to be unsupported by a number of styles - even the more basic (and arguably quite un-exotic - by modern standards at least) URL field is lacking in some styles, simply because they were completed before the advent of the URI, which was standardised in 1994 ([RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)), case in point: [`ieeetr.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/ieeetr.bst) seems to have been the same since 1988 (save for a clarification of the licence).

Having said all that, the `pages` field is probably your best bet for a widely applicable solution, plus it does not seem to be too far off semantically.

But even the treatment of the `pages` field is not standardised or normalised across bibliography styles: Some `.bst` styles check whether the `pages` field contains multiple pages in order to decided whether to print "p." or "pp." ([`plain.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/plain.bst) and [`ieeetr.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/ieeetr.bst)), but there is no need to do that in a German style since in both cases the abbreviation will be "S.", consequently [`natdin.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505/natdin.bst) does not care to check for "multiple pages", it behaves differently if a URL is present, though.

[`biblatex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) offers a lot of these functionalities out of the box, so almost all styles make use of them (that is also thanks to the fact that a lot of the `biblatex` styles out there are coded quite well), I have yet to come across a style that tries to implement these checks itself.

`biblatex` will check if the `pages` field actually contains a "page range", page ranges consist of characters recognised as numbers (see `\DeclareNumChars`) and those recognised as range separators/indicators (see `\DeclareRangeChars`) as well as certain other commands (see `\DeclareRangeCommands` and `\DeclarePageCommands`). If the `pages` field contains only characters and commands declared there, it passes the `\ifpages` test. If a `pages` field passes the `\ifpages` test and it is printed with `\mkpageprefix`, the page prefix "p."/"pp." will be added if it does not, the `pages` field is printed as is without a prefix. In fact, we can control the prefix added to the `pages` field as described in §2.3.10 *Pagination*, p. 35, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), we can even define our own prefix (as shown in [Citing specific slides of a presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101461/35864)).

The "pagination scheme" is even settable on a per-entry basis with `pagination` (controls how in-text citations have the `postnote` formatted if it passes `\ifpages`) and `bookpagination` (controls the `pages` and `pagetotal` fields).

So what you could do for these special `pages` fields is to add `bookpagination = {none}` to the corresponding entry (or hope for a character that throws `\ifpages` to false, the `e` in the PLoS entries does exactly that).

An example with `bookpagination = {none}`:

```
@article{Clune22032013,
  author   = {Clune, Jeff and Mouret, Jean-Baptiste and Lipson, Hod}, 
  title    = {The Evolutionary Origins of Modularity},
  volume   = {280}, 
  number   = {1755},
  pages    = {20122863},
  bookpagination = {none},
  date     = {2013}, 
  doi      = {10.1098/rspb.2012.2863},
  eprint   = {http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/280/1755/20122863.full.pdf+html}, 
  journal  = {Proceedings of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences} 
}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Clune22032013,
  author   = {Clune, Jeff and Mouret, Jean-Baptiste and Lipson, Hod}, 
  title    = {The Evolutionary Origins of Modularity},
  volume   = {280}, 
  number   = {1755},
  pages    = {20122863},
  bookpagination = {none},
  date     = {2013}, 
  doi      = {10.1098/rspb.2012.2863}, 
  eprint   = {http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/280/1755/20122863.full.pdf+html}, 
  journal  = {Proceedings of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences} 
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite[3]{Clune22032013}  

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields, note that for in-text references the pages prefix is enabled (and the default `page` one), while the prefix for the journal pages is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Wow! This answer is awesome. I asked this question expecting a very simple answer, but I ended up learning a lot about `bibtex`, `biblatex`, styles etc. Thanks a lot!